# pandas - combine selected columns and rows summing the contents of the cells

Tags: pandas

How would one go about merging certain columns and rows together, such that the values of the merged cells are summed?

Currently I have a pandas dataframe of the number of flights between airports. However, I need the number of flights between cities.

I have a dictionary with city names as keys and lists of airport id codes as the values. Is there a way I can combine the rows and columns of airports associated with the same city?

The dictionary:

```
{'Akron': ['AKC', 'CAK', 'AKO'],
 'Albany': ['ALB', 'ABY', 'ALH'],
 'Albuquerque': ['ABQ'],
 'Allentown': ['ABE'],
 'Atlanta': ['ATL', 'FTY', 'PDK', 'RYY', 'FFC'],
 'Austin': ['AUS'],
 'Baltimore': ['BWI', 'MTN'],
 'Baton Rouge': ['BTR'],
 ...
 # so on and so forth
```

Segment of the dataframe of crosstabulated flight numbers:

```
DEST    ABE  ABQ  ABY  ALB   ATL  AUS  AVP  BHM  BNA  
ORIGIN                                                  
ABE       0    0    0    0   128    0    1    0    0    
ABQ       0    0    0    0   181   24    0    4    0    
ABY       0    0    0    0    82    0    0    0    0    
ALB       0    0    0    0   196    4    0    0    1    
ATL     132  181   95  224     0  668   71  672  634    
AUS       0   20    0    0   655    0    0    1  116    
AVP       0    0    0    0    63    0    0    0    0    
BHM       0    3    0    0   640    0    0    0    4    
BNA       0    0    0    0   661  105    0    4    0
```

I would like to produce a dataframe like this:

```
 DEST        Akron Albany Albuquerque Allentown Atlanta ....
 ORIGIN
 Akron         0     19       34         0         59     
 Albany       10      0        3        15         21     
 Albuquerque  13      3        0        14          3    
 Allentown     0     10       17         0          5    
 Atlanta      50     21       23         2          0    
 ...
```

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, create the replace dict from your dict, and `replace` the column and index with the city name , then we do `sum`

```
s={'Akron': ['AKC', 'CAK', 'AKO'],
 'Albany': ['ALB', 'ABY', 'ALH'],
 'Albuquerque': ['ABQ'],
 'Allentown': ['ABE'],
 'Atlanta': ['ATL', 'FTY', 'PDK', 'RYY', 'FFC'],
 'Austin': ['AUS'],
 'Baltimore': ['BWI', 'MTN'],
 'Baton Rouge': ['BTR']}

s1=pd.Series(s).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()

dicttoreplace=dict(zip(s1[0],s1['level_0']))


df.columns=pd.Series(df.columns).replace(dicttoreplace)
df.index=pd.Series(df.index).replace(dicttoreplace)

df.sum(axis=1,level=0).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Nice, I was on the same route.  +1